# Invalid sonar.source property when SonarQube is on different Server and Jenkins on different Server

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

Currently I am working on integrating SonarQube with Jenkins using the  SonarQube plugin. The problem I am facing is that my Jenkins is running on different Server than SonarQube. So when I am passing sonar.source property like `$workspace/src` it is not able to find the Jenkins workspace of my repo created by Jenkins due to the different server locations

My project is maven. Below are the details of sonar properties:

```
sonar.projectKey=$POM_GROUPID:$POM_ARTIFACTID
sonar.projectName=$POM_DISPLAYNAME
sonar.projectVersion=$POM_VERSION
sonar.sources=$WORKSPACE/src
sonar.java.binaries=**/classes/**
```

P.S - when both Jenkins and SonarQube are on same server SonarQube is able to find the source of workspace

How can I pass the `sonar.source` of workspace located on Jenkins server so that sonar is able to locate it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use relative paths. This one is absolute:

```
sonar.sources=$WORKSPACE/src
```

This is relative:

```
sonar.sources=src
```

But this is not a recommended solution of your problem. You have Maven, so you should use [SonarScanner for Maven](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/scan/sonarscanner-for-maven/), steps:

- remove the configuration which you added
- configure sources (two options):

  1. add a new property to your `pom.xml`: `<sonar.sources>pom.xml,src</sonar.sources>`
  2. add parameter to `mvn` command: `-Dsonar.sources=pom.xml,src`
- execute SonarScanner `sonar:sonar`

Example:

```
mvn package sonar:sonar -Dsonar.sources=pom.xml,src
```